# Vercel Serverless sequelize connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, vercel

I'm using Vercl's serverless functions and Sequelize for postgres, i have tested the connection on my local machine using `vercel dev` command and everything is working fine.

but when i deploy it, the connection to postgres RDS is very unpredictable, it sometimes works but if i make two requests 1 minute apart from each other i get

```
ConnectionRefusedError [SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
    at Client._connectionCallback (/var/task/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:172:24)
    at Client._handleErrorWhileConnecting (/var/task/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:305:19)
    at Client._handleErrorEvent (/var/task/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:315:19)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Connection.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at Socket.reportStreamError (/var/task/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:53:12)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3) {
  parent: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16) {
    errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 5432
  },
  original: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16) {
    errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 5432
  }
}
```

i suspected this might be due to serverless nature of Vercel functions, tried to fiddle with pool connections, even tried closing and opening connections after every query but it doesn't seem to be working.

this is my connection

```js
const pg = require('pg');
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

new Sequelize(POSTGRES_DB, POSTGRES_USER_WEB, POSTGRES_USER_WEB_PASSWORD, {
    host: POSTGRES_HOST, //AWS RDS HOST
    dialectModule: pg,
    dialect: 'postgres',
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      idle: 1000,
      handleDisconnects: true
    }
  });
```

this is my vercel.json

```json
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [{ "src": "index.js", "use": "@vercel/node" }],
  "rewrites": [
    { "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "index.js" },
    { "source": "/webhook", "destination": "index.js" },
    { "source": "/v1", "destination": "index.js" }
  ]
}
```

this is the error i get, i still suspect this has to do with pools but i don't know how to configure it.

```
[SequelizeConnectionRefusedError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
    at Client._connectionCallback (/var/task/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:172:24)
```

Comment: while I don't have an answer yet I'm also experiencing this issue - I'm using ElephantSQL as my hosted PostgreSQL service - they have been very helpful in providing possible solutions from their end but still feels like the issue is with the nature of serverless. I'm experimenting with this retry approach https://dev.to/anonyma/how-to-retry-transactions-in-sequelize-5h5c

Comment: @headwinds i ended up switching to prisma, the issues is that sequelize is not able to work with serverless connections and it exhausts the pools that postgres (AWS in my case) provides. I've switched to Prisma and a great tool called PGBouncer that comes with Prisma. i didn't have issues since then. but i had to rewrite half of my application.

Comment: appreciate this feedback - I've heard good things about Prisma - I may try it but for now I want to stick and struggle with Sequelize some more - I know I could possibly use PGBouncer with it too - for anyone else interested, this is my current config which seems to be working better once I set the max connection to 1 and added retry: https://gist.github.com/headwinds/b48ee5aebc74f2858466b0f02a26c359